# No puedo ejecutar commit, para enviar archivos al repositorio

Tags: git, configuración

me surgió un inconveniente con respecto al comando commit. Una vez guardado mi nombre y mi mail. Me vuelve a surgir el inconveniente

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Thomas@DESKTOP-PUVBQA1.(none)')
```

Mas alla de actualizarlo con los comandos `git config user.name "nombre"` y con `git config user.mail "mail"` el error persiste.
Me gustaria saber si hay otra forma. Muchas gracias

Comment: Corriste el comando tal cual está? lo que comentas debajo no usa el modificador `--global`. Y pues no, siempre te va a pedir que te identifiques antes de hacer commit para poder identificar en el log quién hizo qué

Comment: ¿Has usado `git config user.mail`? El comando correcto es `git config user.email`. Y mejor usar la opción `--global` para que esa información quede almacenada en tu "home", en vez de dentro del repositorio. De ese modo será accesible desde cualquier otro repositorio que crees en esa misma máquina

Comment: Problema solucionado. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que definir correctamente tu nombre y correo en el global, por defecto si no lo has configurado git toma el nombre de la máquina en la que estas trabajando.